# Don't start next section until every image float is resolved

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I've a chapter formed by two sections. The problem is, I have two images that should be in the first section but eventually end up in the second.
I read a bit about approaches to the problem using options such as t, p and b, but they didn't quite work for me. I'd just want to know if you can start a section **only after** all images have been placed somewhere and the image buffer is empty.

Thanks!

@David, I'm using a standard regular book class. I already have the images placed correctly in chapters, the problem was with sections. I was sleepy when I posted this question so I put in chapters instead of sections. Thanks again.

@everybody, I tried the `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` command and it worked perfectly for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: How about adding `\let\oldchapter\chapter \def\chapter{\clearpage\oldchapter}` to your preamble?

Comment: You could look at [this list of float-related packages](http://www.ctan.org/topic/float).

Comment: Actually, what about `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`?  Or just use its `\FloatBarrier` command in the places you want it.

Comment: @Werner: doesn't `\chapter` already issue `\clearpage`? Or is that only the `\include` (which IMO is a very good idea once you have something with multiple chapters anyway).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, my thought exactly. What class is this?

Comment: The in the standard book and report classes this is already automatic, and article doesn't have `\chapter`. You must be using a non standard class. Please _always_ post a document that shows the problem.

Comment: Do you mean chapter or section? You used "Chapter" in your title, but describe a float floating past a _section_ which is entirely different thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right. I meant "section" in both title and second sentence, also because I assumed they were working the same way. I'm going to edit the title, thanks.

Comment: \chapter does clearpage anyway (heading is top of page) \section does not, use Jon's comment above so that \section issues a \clearpage if there are pending floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allow marking this question as having been answered, allow me to copy&paste the answer from the comments:

The solution is to use

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

in your document preamble.

Comment: IMHO, for being correct, you should have first asked @jon to convert his/her comment into an answer... If s/he doesn't want to do that, you should, at least, mark your answer as Community Wiki, since the answer is not yours...

Comment: Maybe it's better if I revert the acceptation?